# Wordpress shortcode filtering the_content modifies all posts in a list

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, add-filter

I'm writing a plugin and have code like this:

```
add_shortcode('test','testfunc');

function testfunc(){
   add_filter('the_content','mycontent',20);
}

function mycontent($content){
   return "<p style='color:red'>extra content</p>";
}
```

I have used the shortcode '[test]' on *one* of my posts.

The problem is when a list of posts is shown - for example when using a category view - the content is changed for *all* of the posts displayed - not just the one with the shortcode in it.

Any ideas how I can change it so it only filters the code

Comment: So your shortcode [test] is meant to append content to the end of the content in red? But it does this even though you haven't got the shortcode in your post?

Comment: Clarification:  I'm trying to replace the entire content for a post/page with mycontent.  I've updated my original question slightly...

Comment: Ahh ok I understand now I think the reason it isnt working is the filter is added after the_content hook is called. Ill see if I can think of a solution!

Comment: Had ago below try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi heres a solution is doesn't use a shortcode hook but it searches for it in the content.

```
function content_custom_shortcode($content) {

    // Search for shortcode
    $shortcode = 'test';
    preg_match('/\['.$shortcode.'\]/s', $content, $matches);

    // If custom shortcode exists return custom content else return content
    if (in_array('['.$shortcode.']', $matches)) return "<p style='color:red'>extra content</p>";
    else return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','content_custom_shortcode',20);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but i can't get this to work.  The [test] shortcode is displayed in the content.  Is this because the 'test' shortcode hasn't been added with the add_shortcode() function?

Comment: Ive tested it now and it works. It just searches for the string [test] and turns your custom content else it returns content. Is this correct?

Comment: Fantastic - that's it.  Thanks v much for your patience :)

Answer (score 0):

Any time you display a list of posts and one of them contains the shortcode you've created it will change all following posts that are displayed because you've added it to `the_content`, which is executed on every iteration of [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Remove the filter and it should work as expected.

This will wrap the content that you surround with `[test]` and `[/test]` in the `<p>` tags:

```
add_shortcode('test','testfunc');

function testfunc($atts, $content=NULL){
   return "<p style='color:red'>{$content}</p>";
}
```

If you would like to replace all of the content in the post with replacement text change the variable `{$content}` in the example above to whatever text you would like. You still need to wrap the post content in `[test]` and `[/test]`.

There is an example in the WordPress Codex entry on [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes) that is very similar to this.

Comment: My answer assumes you want to add the "extra content" right where the you have the shortcode tag. If that is not what you want please clarify what you want the code to do and I can update my answer.

Comment: Ah yes -that's exactly right and answers the question, but I'm actually trying to replace the entire content of the post that the shortcode appears on (hence why I was using the filter).  Is this achievable?   ...I've updated the mycontent function in my orignal question,,,

Comment: @BillyTheFish I've updated my answer to reflect changes in your question.

Comment: Thanks - this is getting very close to what I need.  But is it possible to do this without a closing shortcode [/test]?